# Why does Rails order the 7 routes created from :resources the way it does?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is pure curiosity. Let's say I have a resource "Users" and want to create the standard set of 7 routes for it. In my routes file, I simply enter `resources :users`. When running `rake routes`, this is what we get:

```
     users GET    /users(.:format)           users#index
           POST   /users(.:format)           users#create
  new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)       users#new
 edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)  users#edit
      user GET    /users/:id(.:format)       users#show
           PUT    /users/:id(.:format)       users#update
           DELETE /users/:id(.:format)       users#destroy
```

Is there a specific reason that it's ordered like this? I understand that the first route that matches the request will be used.

My confusion stems from my thought process that the users#show route would be listed 3rd instead of users#new being in that position.

If anyone could give me some insight into this ordering scheme that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no particular reason *why* these are the way that they are, they just are that way.

It probably stems from the old (I'm talking 1.2 days here) scaffold controller layout where the actions were laid out in that order.

The only problem I can imagine you would encounter here is that if you were to have a user with the `id` of `new` it would go to `UsersController#new` first, rather than the ideal `UsersController#show`. The workaround for that is fairly simple: don't let users identify themselves as "new".

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If users#show was listed third, then `/users/new` would try to show the user with `:id` "new".

Comment: Hmm... I meant that the entire row could be listed third, not just the controller/action being swapped.

Comment: No, that's what I meant. Sorry I wasn't clear. A request to `/users/new` would be answered by the first route that matched, in this case, the `users#show` route, interpreted as having "new" for the `:id` value. And as Ryan points out, that's likely to return a 404 error (or muck up your app) and anyway prevent you from ever being able to see the new user form.

Answer (score 0):

I read them as starting from the `:collection` routes and the `:new` routes, then the `:member` routes.